# Validate every value in a 2D array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a 2D array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12345678
            [1] => 56
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 34567822
            [1] => 67
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12324654
            [1] => 98
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 234769O1
            [1] => 45
        )
)
```

I want to check every value, for example if the `$array[0][0]` is 8 digits long and if `$array[0][1]` is between 1 and 100.. but I want to do it for every array so I was thinking a for loop but I can't get it to work.

This is what I tried, and it returns everything altogether:

```
foreach ($data as $student) {
    foreach ($student as $key => $value) {
        echo $student[$key];
    }
}
```

Can I get some help on this please?

Comment: Where's the code for your attempt?

Comment: And what do you want to do with the valid vs invalid values? Do you intend to delete invalid ones, collect them in another array, bail out of the whole thing?

Comment: I just want to mark them as invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample piece of code to start with:

```
foreach ($data as $student) {
    if (strlen($student[0]) == 8 && (1 <= $student[1] && $student[1] <= 100)) {
        echo 'Fits';
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to convert int to string on student. (string) before $student[0]

Comment: PHP will do that implicitly.

Comment: No, I don't, `strlen` does this implicictly.

Comment: alright so I don't even need to use nested loops for this O.o that was unexpected .. for some reason i always thought that if its a 2d array and I want to check every value, i need to use nested loops

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to get all valid items of your array:

```
//your array with valid and invalid items.
$arr = [
    [12345678, 56],
    [34567822, 67],
    [12324654, 98],
    ['234769O1', 45]
];

//filter all items of the array with 8 digits on index 0 and 
//a number between 1 and 100 on index 1.
$valid_arr = array_filter($arr, function($v) {
    return preg_match("/^[0-9]{8}$/", $v[0]) === 1 && $v[1] >= 1 && $v[1] <= 100;
});
```

If you want to get all invalid items of your array, you can use the following instead:

```
$invalid_arr = array_filter($arr, function($v) {
    return !(preg_match("/^[0-9]{8}$/", $v[0]) === 1 && $v[1] >= 1 && $v[1] <= 100);
});
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/LP3VM6

---

If you need to use a `foreach` loop you can use the following solution:

```
$arr = [
    [12345678, 56],
    [34567822, 67],
    [12324654, 98],
    ['234769O1', 45]
];

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{8}$/", $item[0]) === 1 && $item[1] >= 1 && $item[1] <= 100) {
        echo $item[0].':'.$item[1];
    }
}
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/X8XIp8

Answer (score 1):

If you need them removed you can filter the array:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($v) {
                                  return strlen($v[0]) == 8 &&
                                         $v[1] > 0 &&
                                         $v[1] < 101;
                              }
```

If you need an additional numeric check then:

```
return strlen($v[0]) == 8 &&
       is_numeric($v[0])  &&
       $v[1] > 0 && $v[1] < 101;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do somethig like this:

```
$array =  array(
    array(12345678,56),
    array(34567822,67),
    array(123123312,123),
    array(123123,33),
    array(12324654,98),
    array(23476901,45),
    array(1231412,101),
);

foreach($array as $a) {
    if(strlen($a[0]) == 8 && $a[1] > 1 && $a[1] < 100) {
        // conditions met
    } else {
        // conditions not met
    }
}
```

I added some elements in array that will not pass the test.

In your example you wrote `[0] => 234769O1` where you used letter **O** instead of digit **0**. Maybe this is error in your code.